What do these horizontal stripes signify in the movie Men of Honor
In the famous scene, 12 steps from Men of Honor, we see Master Chief Leslie Sunday wears two groups chevrons on his left arm.

The first group represents his military rank as a Master Chief,

How about the second group of horizontal chevrons?

We can see them at time stamp 8:14 from this video. 



They are not horizontal stripes they are diagonal stripes.

These are Length of Service Stripes

All personnel wear one stripe for each four years of active duty service or reserve service in an active status in any of the armed services.

Wikipedia

A service stripe is an embroidered diagonal stripe worn on the sleeve(s) of some military and paramilitary uniforms. In the case of the United States military, service stripes are authorized for wear by enlisted personnel on the lower part of the sleeve of a uniform to denote length of service. Service stripes vary in size and in color.


Master Chief Sunday's stripes are actually an anachronism: Once a sailor has accumulated 12 or more years of service they are entitled to switch to gold stripes. He shows 7 stripes, or 28 years and they should all be gold.

That's probably true now, but was it then?

Hah, point taken, research ahead. :p

"they revert back to the standard stripes if the Sailor fails to meet the Good Conduct standards of the two aforementioned medals."

"Until June 2019, the service had to have been free of disciplinary action in the U.S. Navy and U.S. Navy Reserve. During the period when that rule was in effect, in cases where a disciplinary infraction had occurred, the sailor was not denied a service stripe but simply was authorized the standard red stripe design only." - Wikipedia

yep, just found that and he most likely had not qualified for the GCM for some period, and lost the right to wear the gold stripes. So, the red was in fact, correct, my bad.

Hey we all learn something, me included.
